# Yafaray Export Button doesn't show in Blender Render Menu

Tags: rendering, game-engine, interface, blender-internal-render-engine

I hope some of you are familiar with the open source render engine yafaray. I just installed it because I am working on a project where I have to render some interior camera animations. I read a lot about cycles being pain in the ass when it comes to interior scences and since my computer isn't fast at all, I was looking for some alternatives to improve my render Time. That's when I found Yafaray.

Now I downloaded the engine from the following (I got this link from the official Yafaray Page):
http://www.jensverwiebe.de/Jens_Verwiebe/Software.html

I guess it's the most recent software and I run Blender 2.71 .

Now, my problem is, that the promised "Yafaray Export"-Button doesn't show up in my Render menu list.

Does any of you may know why?

Thanks for your help in advance!
Marten

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change render engines. I'm not sure that the Yafaray plugin exports the XML (I don't have Blender open now so I can't check). The same dropdown you use to change the render engine from Blender Internal to Cycles is the one you use to change to Yafaray. However, you'll need to enable the Yafaray plugin (Preferences, Addons).